# I'm getting this error ImportError: cannot import name 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' from 'itsdangerous' as Im watching a video by Corey MSchafer

Tags: python, flask

I want to generate a secure time-sensitive token that I can use to ensure that only someone who has access to the user's email can reset their password using the Powershell terminal.

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
```

but I'm getting this error after typing that

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' from 'itsdangerous' (C:\Users\User\Flask\flask\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

As from itsdangerous 2.0.0, TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer is [deprecated](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/?highlight=timedjsonwebsignatureserializer#version-2-0-0)

> JWS support (JSONWebSignatureSerializer, TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer) is deprecated. Use a dedicated JWS/JWT library such as authlib instead. #129

Alternatives include [authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/index.html) but also the excellent [pyjwt](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)